# "Vary for Traits" button not shown on storyboard

Tags: xcode

I'm on Xcode 9.4.1 and usually there is a "very for Trait" button in the right side of the pane where you can configure the device the storyboard should display. But for one app, I only see iPhone in the device pane (I don't see iPad) and I can't see the "Vary for Trait" button in the storyboard, is there any setting I need to configure to have it shown?

Answer (score 1):

When viewing your storyboard / xib in Interface Builder, make sure the right pane is open (or click the button in the top right farthest to the right)

Make sure you have selected the root view for which you wish to have traits enabled.

Click the document icon to open the general document panel (with the first category of "Identity and Type")

Enable "Use Trait Variations" under "Interface Builder Document"

This will enable the "Vary for Traits" button, along with the various + buttons throughout the document and view options.